# Php htaccess get request

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a script that processes get requests and there are 3 buttons, the cators send these requests.

```php
<div class="lang">
    <a href="?lang=ru" class="btn">RU</a>
    <a href="lang=en" class="btn">EN</a>
    <a href="lang=hy" class="btn">HY</a>
</div>

// php script
$bd_name = 'en';
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    if ($_GET['lang'] == 'ru') {
        $bd_name = 'ru';
    }  
    else if ($_GET['lang'] == 'hy') {
        $bd_name = 'hy';
    }
}
```

when you click on the button, the address bar will be like this
www.domain/home?lang=ru
But you need to have
www.domain/home/ru

in htaccess has code

```
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/?$ ?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but this code does not work, I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Hi Hovik, welcome to StackOverflow! I'd encourage you to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and update your answer with some of the recommended strategies from there. It's unclear what your actual question is here to me, so it may need to be rephrased.

Comment: mthrsj  is this clear?